# Access DAO Get newly created record ID by using a stored Append Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I am trying to get the last added Record Id but cant seem to get the recordset to load. I keep on getting "Runtime Error 3219 Invalid Operation". What am I doing wrong?

```
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set qry = db.QueryDefs("AASourceApp")

        'qry.Parameters.Refresh
        qry.Parameters("[Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![cmbUpgradeTo]") = [Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![cmbUpgradeTo]
        qry.Parameters("[Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![SourceID]") = [Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![SourceID]
        'qry.Execute  'if unquoted qry.execute works without a problem

        'Determine newly created record id
        Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset()   ''''''ERROR - Invalid Operation''''''
        Debug.Print rs.LastModified

        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing
```

Here is the stored SQL for the AASourceApp query:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![SourceID] Long, [Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![cmbUpgradeTo] Short;
    INSERT INTO [SourcDoc Tbl] ( [SourceID Link], [SubAccount ID], SourcTypeID, SDate )
    SELECT [SourcDoc Tbl].SourceID, [SourcDoc Tbl].[SubAccount ID], [Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![cmbUpgradeTo] AS DocType, Date() AS Date1
    FROM [SourcDoc Tbl]
    WHERE ((([SourcDoc Tbl].SourceID)=[Forms]![AAAccounts Form]![AASourcDoc Subform].[Form]![SourceID]));
```

Comment: It shouldnt return any data though.  You need a query after to get the latest, i dont think you can do this way.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldnt return any data though.  You need a query after to get the latest, i dont think you can do this way.  Perhaps a select with the same criteria and parameters?